# Трансляция аудиопотока через Icecast

Tags: linux, аудио, icecast

Каким образом можно на Linux организовать трансляцию воспроизводимого звука (например, с аудиопроигрывателя) через Icecast?

Comment: Тебе готовый конфиг айскаста выложить или чего?

Comment: Если дело только в одном конфиге, то да

Comment: Ок, ща покопаюсь в архивах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo aptitude -y install mpd ncmpcpp icecast2
```

Сама музыка лежит в `/var/lib/mpd/music/`. Можно кидать прям туда, можно в каталоге создать симлинк на существующий каталог, можно `bind`. Всё будет пахать.

`/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml`:

```xml
<icecast>
    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- If enabled, this will provide a burst of data when a client 
             first connects, thereby significantly reducing the startup 
             time for listeners that do substantial buffering. However,
             it also significantly increases latency between the source
             client and listening client.  For low-latency setups, you
             might want to disable this. -->
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>Super Secret Passw0rd</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>Super Secret Passw0rd</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>Super Secret Passw0rd</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <!-- set the mountpoint for a shoutcast source to use, the default if not
         specified is /stream but you can change it here if an alternative is
         wanted or an extension is required
    <shoutcast-mount>/live.nsv</shoutcast-mount>
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want directory listings -->
    <!--
    <directory>
        <yp-url-timeout>15</yp-url-timeout>
        <yp-url>http://dir.xiph.org/cgi-bin/yp-cgi</yp-url>
    </directory>
     -->

    <!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
    It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
    listings. -->
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <!-- <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address> -->
        <shoutcast-mount>/mpd.ogg</shoutcast-mount>
    </listen-socket>
    <!--
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8001</port>
    </listen-socket>
    -->

    <!--<master-server>127.0.0.1</master-server>-->
    <!--<master-server-port>8001</master-server-port>-->
    <!--<master-update-interval>120</master-update-interval>-->
    <!--<master-password>hackme</master-password>-->

    <!-- setting this makes all relays on-demand unless overridden, this is
         useful for master relays which do not have <relay> definitions here.
         The default is 0 -->
    <!--<relays-on-demand>1</relays-on-demand>-->

    <!--
    <relay>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>8001</port>
        <mount>/example.ogg</mount>
        <local-mount>/different.ogg</local-mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>

        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    -->

    <!-- Only define a <mount> section if you want to use advanced options,
         like alternative usernames or passwords
    <mount>
        <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>

        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>

        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/example_intro.ogg</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <no-yp>1</no-yp>
        <authentication type="htpasswd">
                <option name="filename" value="myauth"/>
                <option name="allow_duplicate_users" value="0"/>
        </authentication>
        <on-connect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-start</on-connect>
        <on-disconnect>/home/icecast/bin/stream-stop</on-disconnect>
    </mount>

    <mount>
        <mount-name>/auth_example.ogg</mount-name>
        <authentication type="url">
            <option name="mount_add"       value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="mount_remove"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_mount.php"/>
            <option name="listener_add"    value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
            <option name="listener_remove" value="http://myauthserver.net/notify_listener.php"/>
        </authentication>
    </mount>

    -->

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <!-- basedir is only used if chroot is enabled -->
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>

        <!-- Note that if <chroot> is turned on below, these paths must both
             be relative to the new root, not the original root -->
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <!-- <pidfile>/usr/share/icecast2/icecast.pid</pidfile> -->

        <!-- Aliases: treat requests for 'source' path as being for 'dest' path
             May be made specific to a port or bound address using the "port"
             and "bind-address" attributes.
          -->
        <!--
        <alias source="/foo" dest="/bar"/>
          -->
        <!-- Aliases: can also be used for simple redirections as well,
             this example will redirect all requests for http://server:port/ to
             the status page
          -->
        <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <!-- <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog> -->
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
        <!-- If logarchive is enabled (1), then when logsize is reached
             the logfile will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.DATESTAMP,
             otherwise it will be moved to [error|access|playlist].log.old.
             Default is non-archive mode (i.e. overwrite)
        -->
        <!-- <logarchive>1</logarchive> -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        <!--
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nogroup</group>
        </changeowner>
        -->
    </security>
</icecast>
```

`/etc/mpd.conf`:

```
# An example configuration file for MPD 
# See the mpd.conf man page for a more detailed description of each parameter. 


# Files and directories ####################################################### 
# 
# This setting controls the top directory which MPD will search to discover the 
# available audio files and add them to the daemon's online database. This  
# setting defaults to the XDG directory, otherwise the music directory will be 
# be disabled and audio files will only be accepted over ipc socket (using 
# file:// protocol) or streaming files over an accepted protocol. 
# 
music_directory     "/var/lib/mpd/music" 
# 
# This setting sets the MPD internal playlist directory. The purpose of this 
# directory is storage for playlists created by MPD. The server will use  
# playlist files not created by the server but only if they are in the MPD 
# format. This setting defaults to playlist saving being disabled. 
# 
playlist_directory      "/var/lib/mpd/playlists" 
# 
# This setting sets the location of the MPD database. This file is used to 
# load the database at server start up and store the database while the  
# server is not up. This setting defaults to disabled which will allow 
# MPD to accept files over ipc socket (using file:// protocol) or streaming 
# files over an accepted protocol. 
# 
db_file         "/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache" 
#  
# These settings are the locations for the daemon log files for the daemon. 
# These logs are great for troubleshooting, depending on your log_level 
# settings. 
# 
# The special value "syslog" makes MPD use the local syslog daemon. This 
# setting defaults to logging to syslog, otherwise logging is disabled. 
# 
log_file            "/var/log/mpd/mpd.log" 
# 
# This setting sets the location of the file which stores the process ID 
# for use of mpd --kill and some init scripts. This setting is disabled by 
# default and the pid file will not be stored. 
# 
pid_file            "/var/run/mpd/pid" 
# 
# This setting sets the location of the file which contains information about 
# most variables to get MPD back into the same general shape it was in before 
# it was brought down. This setting is disabled by default and the server  
# state will be reset on server start up. 
# 
state_file          "/var/lib/mpd/state" 
# 
# The location of the sticker database.  This is a database which 
# manages dynamic information attached to songs. 
# 
sticker_file                   "/var/lib/mpd/sticker.sql" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# General music daemon options ################################################ 
# 
# This setting specifies the user that MPD will run as. MPD should never run as 
# root and you may use this setting to make MPD change its user ID after 
# initialization. This setting is disabled by default and MPD is run as the 
# current user. 
# 
user                "mpd" 
# 
# This setting specifies the group that MPD will run as. If not specified 
# primary group of user specified with "user" setting will be used (if set). 
# This is useful if MPD needs to be a member of group such as "audio" to 
# have permission to use sound card. 
# 
#group                          "nogroup" 
# 
# This setting sets the address for the daemon to listen on. Careful attention 
# should be paid if this is assigned to anything other then the default, any. 
# This setting can deny access to control of the daemon. Choose any if you want 
# to have mpd listen on every address 
# 
# For network 
bind_to_address     "localhost" 
# 
# And for Unix Socket 
#bind_to_address        "/var/run/mpd/socket" 
# 
# This setting is the TCP port that is desired for the daemon to get assigned 
# to. 
# 
#port               "6600" 
# 
# This setting controls the type of information which is logged. Available  
# setting arguments are "default", "secure" or "verbose". The "verbose" setting 
# argument is recommended for troubleshooting, though can quickly stretch 
# available resources on limited hardware storage. 
# 
#log_level          "default" 
# 
# If you have a problem with your MP3s ending abruptly it is recommended that  
# you set this argument to "no" to attempt to fix the problem. If this solves 
# the problem, it is highly recommended to fix the MP3 files with vbrfix 
# (available as vbrfix in the debian archive), at which 
# point gapless MP3 playback can be enabled. 
# 
#gapless_mp3_playback           "yes" 
# 
# This setting enables MPD to create playlists in a format usable by other 
# music players. 
# 
#save_absolute_paths_in_playlists   "no" 
# 
# This setting defines a list of tag types that will be extracted during the  
# audio file discovery process. Optionally, 'comment' can be added to this 
# list. 
# 
#metadata_to_use    "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date,composer,performer,disc" 
# 
# This setting enables automatic update of MPD's database when files in  
# music_directory are changed. 
# 
#auto_update    "yes" 
# 
# Limit the depth of the directories being watched, 0 means only watch 
# the music directory itself.  There is no limit by default. 
# 
#auto_update_depth "3" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Symbolic link behavior ###################################################### 
# 
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following  
# symbolic links outside of the configured music_directory. 
# 
#follow_outside_symlinks    "yes" 
# 
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following 
# symbolic links inside of the configured music_directory. 
# 
#follow_inside_symlinks     "yes" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Zeroconf / Avahi Service Discovery ########################################## 
# 
# If this setting is set to "yes", service information will be published with 
# Zeroconf / Avahi. 
# 
zeroconf_enabled        "yes" 
# 
# The argument to this setting will be the Zeroconf / Avahi unique name for 
# this MPD server on the network. 
# 
zeroconf_name           "mpd@lunex" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Permissions ################################################################# 
# 
# If this setting is set, MPD will require password authorization. The password 
# can setting can be specified multiple times for different password profiles. 
# 
#password                        "password@read,add,control,admin" 
# 
# This setting specifies the permissions a user has who has not yet logged in.  
# 
#default_permissions             "read,add,control,admin" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Input ####################################################################### 
# 

#input { 
#       plugin "curl" 
#       proxy "http://proxy.expample.ru:3128" 
#       proxy_user "user" 
#       proxy_password "password" 
#} 

# 
############################################################################### 

# Audio Output ################################################################ 
# 
# MPD supports various audio output types, as well as playing through multiple  
# audio outputs at the same time, through multiple audio_output settings  
# blocks. Setting this block is optional, though the server will only attempt 
# autodetection for one sound card. 
# 
# See <http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Configuration#Audio_Outputs> for examples of  
# other audio outputs. 
# 
# An example of an ALSA output: 
# 
audio_output { 
    type        "alsa" 
    name        "My ALSA Device" 
    device      "hw:0,0"    # optional 
    format      "44100:16:2"    # optional 
    mixer_device    "default"   # optional 
    mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional 
    mixer_index "0"     # optional 
} 
# 
# An example of an OSS output: 
# 
#audio_output { 
#   type        "oss" 
#   name        "My OSS Device" 
#   device      "/dev/dsp"  # optional 
#   format      "44100:16:2"    # optional 
#   mixer_device    "/dev/mixer"    # optional 
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional 
#} 
# 
# An example of a shout output (for streaming to Icecast): 
# 
audio_output { 
    type        "shout" 
    encoding    "ogg"           # optional 
    name        "Rock music" 
    host        "localhost" 
    port        "8000" 
    mount       "/mpd.ogg" 
    password    "123" 
    quality     "5.0" 
#   bitrate     "128" 
    format      "44100:16:1" 
    protocol    "icecast2"      # optional 
#   user        "source"        # optional 
    description "Rock-n-roll alive!"    # optional 
    genre       "rock"          # optional 
    public      "yes"           # optional 
#   timeout     "2"         # optional 
} 
# 
# An example of a recorder output: 
# 
#audio_output { 
#       type            "recorder" 
#       name            "My recorder" 
#       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional, vorbis or lame 
#       path            "/var/lib/mpd/recorder/mpd.ogg" 
##      quality         "5.0"                   # do not define if bitrate is defined 
#       bitrate         "128"                   # do not define if quality is defined 
#       format          "44100:16:1" 
#} 
# 
# An example of a httpd output (built-in HTTP streaming server): 
# 
audio_output { 
    type        "httpd" 
    name        "Cosy little radio" 
    genre       "Rock-n-roll, rock, blues" 
    website     "http://my-host/music" 
    encoder     "lame"          # optional, vorbis or lame 
    port        "1968" 
#   quality     "5.0"           # do not define if bitrate is defined 
    bitrate     "128"           # do not define if quality is defined 
    format      "44100:16:1" 
} 
# 
# An example of a pulseaudio output (streaming to a remote pulseaudio server) 
# 
#audio_output { 
#   type        "pulse" 
#   name        "My Pulse Output" 
#   server      "remote_server"     # optional 
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional 
#} 
# 
## Example "pipe" output: 
# 
#audio_output { 
#   type        "pipe" 
#   name        "my pipe" 
#   command     "aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null" 
## Or if you're want to use AudioCompress 
#   command     "AudioCompress -m | aplay -f cd 2>/dev/null" 
## Or to send raw PCM stream through PCM: 
#   command     "nc example.org 8765" 
#   format      "44100:16:2" 
#} 
# 
## An example of a null output (for no audio output): 
# 
#audio_output { 
#   type        "null" 
#   name        "My Null Output" 
#} 
# 
# This setting will change all decoded audio to be converted to the specified 
# format before being passed to the audio outputs. By default, this setting is 
# disabled. 
# 
#audio_output_format        "44100:16:2" 
# 
# If MPD has been compiled with libsamplerate support, this setting specifies  
# the sample rate converter to use.  Possible values can be found in the  
# mpd.conf man page or the libsamplerate documentation. By default, this is 
# setting is disabled. 
# 
#samplerate_converter       "Fastest Sinc Interpolator" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Volume control mixer ######################################################## 
# 
# These are the global volume control settings. By default, this setting will 
# be detected to the available audio output device, with preference going to  
# hardware mixing. Hardware and software mixers for individual audio_output 
# sections cannot yet be mixed. 
# 
# An example for controlling an ALSA, OSS or Pulseaudio mixer; If this 
# setting is used other sound applications will be affected by the volume 
# being controlled by MPD. 
# 
#mixer_type         "hardware" 
# 
# An example for controlling all mixers through software. This will control 
# all controls, even if the mixer is not supported by the device and will not 
# affect any other sound producing applications. 
# 
mixer_type          "software" 
# 
# This example will not allow MPD to touch the mixer at all and will disable 
# all volume controls. 
# 
#mixer_type         "disabled" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Normalization automatic volume adjustments ################################## 
# 
# This setting specifies the type of ReplayGain to use. This setting can have 
# the argument "album" or "track". See <http://www.replaygain.org> for more 
# details. This setting is disabled by default. 
# 
#replaygain         "album" 
# 
# This setting sets the pre-amp used for files that have ReplayGain tags. By 
# default this setting is disabled. 
# 
#replaygain_preamp      "0" 
# 
# This setting enables on-the-fly normalization volume adjustment. This will 
# result in the volume of all playing audio to be adjusted so the output has  
# equal "loudness". This setting is disabled by default. 
# 
#volume_normalization       "no" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# MPD Internal Buffering ###################################################### 
# 
# This setting adjusts the size of internal decoded audio buffering. Changing 
# this may have undesired effects. Don't change this if you don't know what you 
# are doing. 
# 
#audio_buffer_size      "2048" 
# 
# This setting controls the percentage of the buffer which is filled before  
# beginning to play. Increasing this reduces the chance of audio file skipping,  
# at the cost of increased time prior to audio playback. 
# 
#buffer_before_play     "10%" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Resource Limitations ######################################################## 
# 
# These settings are various limitations to prevent MPD from using too many 
# resources. Generally, these settings should be minimized to prevent security 
# risks, depending on the operating resources. 
# 
#connection_timeout     "60" 
#max_connections        "10" 
#max_playlist_length        "16384" 
#max_command_list_size      "2048" 
#max_output_buffer_size     "8192" 
# 
############################################################################### 


# Character Encoding ########################################################## 
# 
# If file or directory names do not display correctly for your locale then you  
# may need to modify this setting. After modification of this setting mpd  
# --create-db must be run to change the database. 
# 
filesystem_charset      "UTF-8" 
# 
# This setting controls the encoding that ID3v1 tags should be converted from. 
# 
id3v1_encoding          "UTF-8" 
# 
############################################################################### 
# SIDPlay decoder ############################################################# 
# 
# songlength_database: 
#  Location of your songlengths file, as distributed with the HVSC. 
#  The sidplay plugin checks this for matching MD5 fingerprints. 
#  See http://www.c64.org/HVSC/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.faq 
# 
# default_songlength: 
#  This is the default playing time in seconds for songs not in the 
#  songlength database, or in case you're not using a database. 
#  A value of 0 means play indefinitely. 
# 
# filter: 
#  Turns the SID filter emulation on or off. 
# 
#decoder { 
#       plugin                  "sidplay" 
#       songlength_database     "/media/C64Music/DOCUMENTS/Songlengths.txt" 
#       default_songlength      "120" 
#       filter "true" 
#} 
# 
###############################################################################
```

P.S. Тестировалось (и до сих пор работает) на ubuntu 12.04 i686. Как на более новых будет себя вести и что там поломали\поменяли - хз.