# Помогите с отправкой аудио потока в локальную сеть

Tags: ubuntu, http, аудио

У меня не получается сделать веб радио (пока в локальной сети). Прошарил весь интернет, ничего не нашел. Есть такая радиостанция: http://prmstrm.1.fm:8000/ajazz , хотелось бы сделать что-то похожее. Также, у меня есть ноут с Ubuntu (если это поможет).

Comment: Если вы откроете просто http://prmstrm.1.fm:8000/ то увидите, что тут используется сервер Icecast — вот про него и прошарьте весь интернет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661623/191416